# How to re-permute the axes of a tensor in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

My code is like，

```
 user_item_matrix = K.constant(user_item_matrix)
    # Input variables
    user_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='user_input')
    item_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='item_input')
    # Embedding layer
    user_rating = Lambda(lambda x: tf.gather(user_item_matrix, tf.to_int32(x), axis=0))(user_input)
    item_rating = Lambda(lambda x: tf.gather(user_item_matrix, tf.to_int32(x), axis=1))(item_input)
```

where user_item_matrix is a 6040*3706 matrix. The shapes of user_rating and item_rating are suppose to be (?, 3706) and (?, 6040). However, the real situation is:

```
user_rating:  (?, 1, 3706)
item_rating:  (6040, ?, 1)
```

I'm confused about why 6040 took place at axis 0 where is suppose to be ? (the batch size). I try to use Permute and Reshape to solve this problem but still not working. Is there a good solution to solve such problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) about `tf.gather()`:

> Produces an output tensor with shape **params.shape[:axis] +
>   indices.shape + params.shape[axis + 1:]**

Your shape of params is `(6040,3706)` and shape of indices is `(?,1)`.

So the shape of  output is `params.shape[:0] + indices.shape + params.shape[1:]` = `() + (?,1) + (3706,)` when set `axis=0`.

And the shape of  output is `params.shape[:1] + indices.shape + params.shape[2:]` = `(6040,) + (?,1) + ()` when set `axis=1`.

You can use `tf.transpose()` to re-permute the axes.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Input,Lambda
import numpy as np

user_item_matrix = K.constant(np.zeros(shape=(6040,3706)))
# Input variables
user_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='user_input')
item_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='item_input')
# Embedding layer
user_rating = Lambda(lambda x: tf.gather(user_item_matrix, tf.to_int32(x), axis=0))(K.squeeze(user_input,axis=1))
item_rating = Lambda(lambda x: tf.transpose(tf.gather(user_item_matrix, tf.to_int32(x), axis=1),(1,0)))(K.squeeze(item_input,axis=1))
print(user_rating.shape)
print(item_rating.shape)

# print
(?, 3706)
(?, 6040)
```

Comment: Thank you! This perfectly address my problem!